# printing list and nested list side by side

Tags: python, nested-lists

Direct to the Question.
two lists. one is nested and another one is normal one.

```
a = ['Name', 'Age', 'Class', 'Marks', 'Grade']
b = [['n1', 12, '1st', 40, 'b'],
     ['n2', 14, '1st', 70, 'a'],
     ['n3', 16, '2nd', 90, 's'],
     ['n4', 14, '3rd', 40, 'b'],
     ['n5', 12, '1st', 50, 'b'],
     ['n6', 18, '3rd', 30, 'c'],
     ['n7', 11, '1st', 80, 'a'],
     ['n8', 10, '2nd', 20, 'd']]
```

How to print above two lists like this(side by side and without , []).

```
Name   : n1
Age    : 12
Class  : 1st
Marks  : 40
Grade  : b
```

similarly, it needs to print in the same manner to all the students.

```
def details():
    for i in b:
        for j in i:
            for k in a:
```

then i stuck there. I tried zip(a,b) mixing with enumerate but its not working.
Since, i am new to Python, i cant figure it out. Please help on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you mention expected output more elaborate? Does all the student information should come in side.

Comment: `print(*(f"{k}\t: {v}" for i in b for k, v in zip(a, i)), sep="\n")` or `print("\n---\n".join("\n".join(f"{k}\t: {v}" for k, v in zip(a, i)) for i in b))`

Comment: No. just one student set then other one. like boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this with `enumerate`:

```
for i in b:
    for idx,j in enumerate(i):
        print("{:<5}".format(a[idx]),":",j)
```

Comment: thanks it helped. But is saw some items are zigzagged in printing. Like some items in b are left sided and some are right aliening, why?

Comment: Glad it helps you :).That's because the different lenghts of the strings,. Try the last edit of my answer using format, see helpful info about format [here](https://pyformat.info/). If it helps you, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I'll appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply loop over the list of lists `b` and zip each inner list with the keys from `a`:

```
a = ['Name', 'Age', 'Class', 'Marks', 'Grade']
b = [['n1', 12, '1st', 40, 'b'],
     ['n2', 14, '1st', 70, 'a'],
     ['n3', 16, '2nd', 90, 's'],
     ['n4', 14, '3rd', 40, 'b'],
     ['n5', 12, '1st', 50, 'b'],
     ['n6', 18, '3rd', 30, 'c'],
     ['n7', 11, '1st', 80, 'a'],
     ['n8', 10, '2nd', 20, 'd']]

for inner in b:
     for key, value in zip(a, inner):
          print(f"{key:<5} : {value}")
     print()
```

Output:

```
Name  : n1
Age   : 12
Class : 1st
Marks : 40
Grade : b

Name  : n2
Age   : 14
Class : 1st
Marks : 70
Grade : a

Name  : n3
Age   : 16
Class : 2nd
Marks : 90
Grade : s

Name  : n4
Age   : 14
Class : 3rd
Marks : 40
Grade : b

Name  : n5
Age   : 12
Class : 1st
Marks : 50
Grade : b

Name  : n6
Age   : 18
Class : 3rd
Marks : 30
Grade : c

Name  : n7
Age   : 11
Class : 1st
Marks : 80
Grade : a

Name  : n8
Age   : 10
Class : 2nd
Marks : 20
Grade : d
```

---

See [string format mini language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for formatting your string with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can access simply like this

```
for i in b:
    for j in range(len(a)):
        print(a[j]+" : "+str(i[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
a = ['Name', 'Age', 'Class', 'Marks', 'Grade']
b = [['n1', 12, '1st', 40, 'b'],
     ['n2', 14, '1st', 70, 'a'],
     ['n3', 16, '2nd', 90, 's'],
     ['n4', 14, '3rd', 40, 'b'],
     ['n5', 12, '1st', 50, 'b'],
     ['n6', 18, '3rd', 30, 'c'],
     ['n7', 11, '1st', 80, 'a'],
     ['n8', 10, '2nd', 20, 'd']]

for lst in b:
    for t in [n for n in zip(a,lst)]: # For tuple in the list of tuples generated by zip()
        print(f"{t[0].ljust(7)}: {t[1]}") # Print the 0 index (first element) of the tuple with ljust (padding) of 7 spaces, followed by a colon, space, and the 1 index (second element) of the tuple
    print('------------')
```

Output:

```
Name   : n1
Age    : 12
Class  : 1st
Marks  : 40
Grade  : b
------------
Name   : n2
Age    : 14
Class  : 1st
Marks  : 70
Grade  : a
------------
Name   : n3
Age    : 16
Class  : 2nd
Marks  : 90
Grade  : s
------------
Name   : n4
Age    : 14
Class  : 3rd
Marks  : 40
Grade  : b
------------
Name   : n5
Age    : 12
Class  : 1st
Marks  : 50
Grade  : b
------------
Name   : n6
Age    : 18
Class  : 3rd
Marks  : 30
Grade  : c
------------
Name   : n7
Age    : 11
Class  : 1st
Marks  : 80
Grade  : a
------------
Name   : n8
Age    : 10
Class  : 2nd
Marks  : 20
Grade  : d
------------
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand this part  print(f"{t[0].ljust(7)}: {t[1]}"). I think its too advanced for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Pythonic-one-liner, with elegant display:

```
print(*[f"{a[x]:6}: {z}" for i in b for x,z in enumerate(i)], sep='\n')
```